# Update observableArray after filtering

Tags: knockout.js

I have afairly simple view model. I have an observableArray `customers`, which can be filtered by calling `viewModel.filterCustomers`. This works fine and my view gets updated. Now I want to have a function the restores the observableArray `customers` and updates the UI when I call `getCachedCustomers`.

If I call:

```
viewModel.customers(viewModel.cachedCustomers());
```

`viewModel.customers()` is not updated. The array still has the filtered elements.

This is a "dumbed down" version of my issue. Any help is appreciated.

```
var viewModel = {
            PageName: "Editor",                               
            filteredCustomers: ko.observableArray([]),
            cachedCustomers: ko.observableArray([]),               
            customers: ko.observableArray([]),
            applyFilter: ko.observableArray([]),               

            getCachedCustomers: function() {

                viewModel.customers(viewModel.cachedCustomers());
                viewModel.customers.valueHasMutated();
                console.log(viewModel.cachedCustomers());

            }

        };

        viewModel.filterCustomers = function() {

            var filter = $('#txtFilter').val();
            if (filter.length < 1) {
                return;
            }
            viewModel.applyFilter = ko.computed(function () {
                viewModel.customers(ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.customers(), function (item, data) {
                    return stringStartsWith(item.CustomerNumber().toLowerCase(), filter.toLowerCase()) || stringStartsWith(item.CustomerName().toLowerCase(), filter.toLowerCase());
                }));
            }, viewModel);

        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like you are making your viewmodel more complex than it needs to be.

In my opinion you do not need to have a `filterCustomers` method, what you need is to have a `filteredCustomers` computed observable:

```
function myViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.customers = ko.observableArray([]);
    //use this observable in your markup to retrieve the filter
    this.searchFilter = ko.observable(''); 
    this.filteredCustomers = ko.computed(function () {
        var tempFilteredCustomers = self.customers();
        if (typeof self.searchFilter() == 'string' && self.searchFilter().length > 0) {
            //apply filter here on tempFilteredCustomers
        }
        return tempFilteredCustomers;
    }
}
```